# Como executar uma função após AngularJS realizar todas requisições get/post?

Tags: angularjs, http-request

Preciso chamar uma function após todas requisições get/post estiverem finalizadas.
Obs: não posso chamar essa função várias vezes!

```
        angular
        .module('app.services')
        .config(InterceptorConfig)
        .service('InterceptorService', InterceptorService);

    function InterceptorConfig($httpProvider) {
        $httpProvider.interceptors.push('InterceptorService');
    }

    InterceptorService.$inject = ['$q', '$rootScope', 'Constants'];

    function InterceptorService($q, $rootScope, Constants) {
      return {
        request: function(config) {
            ##########################

            NÃO POSSO CHAMAR AQUI  

            ########################## 
            if (config.method === 'POST' && !config.file) {
                config.headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
            }

            if (!config.notloader) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast("loader_show");
            }
            return config || $q.when(config);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Tu pode usar o retorno no "success" para executar algo em caso de sucesso ou até mesmo carregar um erro com o retorno "error" de uma chamada http.
Segue o simples exemplo:

```
$http.get('').success(functional(retorno){
  //Faz algo caso de sucesso
}).error(function(msg){
  //Escreve o erro
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Voce pode usar eventos para enviar um evento "carregando:finalizado", por exemplo, e colocar um $scope dentro de um Controller or Directive "ouvindo/listening" aquele evento e executar quando o evento acontecer.

```
angular.module('app.services').factory('InterceptorService', ['$q', '$rootScope',
    function ($q, $rootScope) {
        var loadingCount = 0;

        return {
            request: function (config) {
                if (++loadingCount === 1) $rootScope.$broadcast('carregando:andamento');
                return config || $q.when(config);
            },

            response: function (response) {
                if(--loadingCount === 0) $rootScope.$broadcast('carregando:finalizado');
                return response || $q.when(response); 
            },

            responseError: function (response) {
                if(--loadingCount === 0) $rootScope.$broadcast('carregando:erro');
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        };
     }
 ]).config(['$httpProvider', function ($httpProvider) {
     $httpProvider.interceptors.push('InterceptorService');
}]);
```

Exemplo usando uma Directive:

```
.directive("loader", function ($rootScope) {
    return function ($scope, element, attrs) {
        $scope.$on("carregando:finalizado", function () {
            // chamar uma function aqui - todas requisições get/post foram finalizadas
        });
    };
});
```

Usando um Controller

```
$scope.$on('carregando:finalizado', function (){
     // chamar uma function aqui - todas requisições get/post foram finalizadas
});
```

Comment: Ou voce pode criar uma Directive bem simples que apenas listen por aquele evento e chama a funcao que vc precisa. Ai voce coloca essa directive no header ou footer da applicacao (um lugar generico). Dessa forma essa directive generica iria ser suficiente pra administrar isso.

Comment: if(--loadingCount === 0) $rootScope.$broadcast('carregando:finalizado'); passa mais de uma vez ainda.

Comment: Compreendi muito bem sua solução, já até tinha tentado isso e passei pelo mesmo problema, pelo fato de ser async.

Comment: @MaxFerreira Se todas as requisicoes fizerem parte de um mesmo Service voce poderia usar Promises ($q). Eu respondi uma pergunta similar aqui http://stackoverflow.com/a/18674913/1310945